# Why does MVVM Light's NavigateTo create new activities instead of reusing them?

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvm-light, light

I have followed the Android Xamarin example from here [mvvmlight.net](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/nav4.cshtml).
Both activities extend ActivityBase. When i call _nav.NavigateTo with the proper keys, the other activity is opened, but OnCreate is called every time, and savedInstanceState is always null. 
OnDestroy() and OnSaveInstanceState() are never called. It seems NavigateTo creates a new activity without destroying the last. Is this correct?

When looking at the Android Activity lifecycle, OnCreate should only be called once. How can I just resume the other activity instead of re-creating it every time?

LoginActivity:

```cs
[Activity(Label = "Login", MainLauncher = true, Icon = null)]
public class LoginActivity : ActivityBase
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginLayout);

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        var nav = new NavigationService();

        nav.Configure(Constants.Keys.Main, typeof(MainActivity));
        nav.Configure(Constants.Keys.Login, typeof(LoginActivity));
        nav.Configure(Constants.Keys.Live, typeof(LiveActivity));
        ...

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => nav);
```

LoginLayout.axml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="5dp">
... some buttons etc
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```cs
public class MainActivity : ActivityBase
{
    private INavigationService _nav;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        _nav = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
    }

    private void Settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _nav.NavigateTo(Constants.Keys.Settings, null);
    }
```

main.axml:

```
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/MainLayout">
          <include
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              layout="@layout/toolbar" />
          <LinearLayout
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/main_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
            <Button
                android:text="Live"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonLive"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Alerts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonAlerts" />
            <Button
                android:text="Settings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonSettings" />
          </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new activity on every start activity intent is the default Android behavior, this is not related to MVVMLight in any way.
If you would like to reuse the same activity, you can achieve it by configuring your activity start intent. Have a look at the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

In the case of MVVMLight, it looks like the default [NavigationService.NavigateTo(string pageKey, object parameter)](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform%20(Android)/Views/NavigationService.cs) implementation on Android does not allow to customize the start intent.

If you would like to acheive it, you will have to reimplement your own INavigationService supporting to add the flag to your intent with `intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop)`.

Comment: So are the old activities collected by GC? OnDestroy() is never called as far as I can see. How am I supposed to clean them up?

Comment: I am not really familiar with MVVMLight... I expect it to not keep references to the activities in order to allow them to be collected. Then when the native GC will collect them is not really predictable depending on memory pressure.
For dev purpose, you can force Android to destroy Activities as soon you leave one (it is in the developer settings, "Don't keep activities" in a Nexus 5X)